# Possible to hook IAT function by ordinal?

Tags: c++, hook, code-injection

I am messing around with some dll injection / function hooking. I am able to hook functions of the import address table by name, by comparing the name of the function in the IAT. (Getting IMAGE_THUNK_DATA and reading the value)

But when the application I am injecting into is importing the functions by ordinal I will not have success with that approach. For example sometimes when I check IMAGE_THUNK_DATA* thunkData->u1.Function it appears to be some ordinal number.

Now to my question: Is there a way to get the ordinal number of, for example, the Sleep function ( https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/ms686298(v=vs.85).aspx ) and check if the value in the IAT is equal to that ordinal number?
For example something like this:

```
if (IMAGE_SNAP_BY_ORDINAL(thunkData->u1.Function)) {
    //check if u1.Function is my desired ordinal number of sleep
}
```

Or is the ordinal number in the IAT of my application I am injecting into not the same as the ordinal number of the Sleep function in the original dll?

I hope you understand what I mean.

Comment: @user - you completelly wrong - ordinal not stable. we can not use ordinal for Sleep  - it different in different windows versions.

Comment: @RbMm oh okey thank you. Is there any other solution if, let's say Sleep is imported by ordinal, to hook that function through the IAT?

Comment: Sleep is NEVER imported by ordinal - this is incorrect. however i of course know solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

of course possible hook function by ordinal, **but** if we know this ordinal.

in general ordinals is not stable. so for example `Sleep` have different ordinals in every windows version. even more - in the same widows version it have different ordinals in x86 and x64 versions of `kernel32.dll` - but are `Sleep` imported *by ordinal* in your application ? i 100% sure that not.

however some ordinals is stable, in some dlls (like `ws2_32.dll` or `oleaut32.dll` ). how we can know which ordinals is stable (can be using) ? let think - we use linking `someimport.lib` for import functions from `some.dll` - and in this import `LIB` and containing info how import function - by name or by ordinal. so you need get info from `LIB` file. this can be done by command:

`link.exe -dump /EXPORTS "somepath\somelib.lib" > somelib.log`

let for example take `ws2_32.lib` - i run

`link.exe -dump /EXPORTS "my path\x64\ws2_32.lib" > ws2_32.log`

```
   ordinal    name
          ?WSApSetPostRoutine@@YAHPEAX@Z (int __cdecl WSApSetPostRoutine(void *))
          FreeAddrInfoEx
          FreeAddrInfoExW
          FreeAddrInfoW
          GetAddrInfoExA
          GetAddrInfoExCancel
          GetAddrInfoExOverlappedResult
          GetAddrInfoExW
          GetAddrInfoW
          GetHostNameW
          GetNameInfoW
          InetNtopW
          InetPtonW
          SetAddrInfoExA
          SetAddrInfoExW
   500    WEP
          WPUCompleteOverlappedRequest
          WPUGetProviderPathEx
          WSAAccept
          WSAAddressToStringA
          WSAAddressToStringW
          WSAAdvertiseProvider
   102    WSAAsyncGetHostByAddr
   103    WSAAsyncGetHostByName
   105    WSAAsyncGetProtoByName
   104    WSAAsyncGetProtoByNumber
   107    WSAAsyncGetServByName
   106    WSAAsyncGetServByPort
   101    WSAAsyncSelect
   108    WSACancelAsyncRequest
   113    WSACancelBlockingCall
   116    WSACleanup
          WSACloseEvent
          WSAConnect
          WSAConnectByList
          WSAConnectByNameA
          WSAConnectByNameW
          WSACreateEvent
          WSADuplicateSocketA
          WSADuplicateSocketW
          WSAEnumNameSpaceProvidersA
          WSAEnumNameSpaceProvidersExA
          WSAEnumNameSpaceProvidersExW
          WSAEnumNameSpaceProvidersW
          WSAEnumNetworkEvents
          WSAEnumProtocolsA
          WSAEnumProtocolsW
          WSAEventSelect
   111    WSAGetLastError
          WSAGetOverlappedResult
          WSAGetQOSByName
          WSAGetServiceClassInfoA
          WSAGetServiceClassInfoW
          WSAGetServiceClassNameByClassIdA
          WSAGetServiceClassNameByClassIdW
          WSAHtonl
          WSAHtons
          WSAInstallServiceClassA
          WSAInstallServiceClassW
          WSAIoctl
   114    WSAIsBlocking
          WSAJoinLeaf
          WSALookupServiceBeginA
          WSALookupServiceBeginW
          WSALookupServiceEnd
          WSALookupServiceNextA
          WSALookupServiceNextW
          WSANSPIoctl
          WSANtohl
          WSANtohs
          WSAPoll
          WSAProviderCompleteAsyncCall
          WSAProviderConfigChange
          WSARecv
          WSARecvDisconnect
          WSARecvFrom
          WSARemoveServiceClass
          WSAResetEvent
          WSASend
          WSASendDisconnect
          WSASendMsg
          WSASendTo
   109    WSASetBlockingHook
          WSASetEvent
   112    WSASetLastError
          WSASetServiceA
          WSASetServiceW
          WSASocketA
          WSASocketW
   115    WSAStartup
          WSAStringToAddressA
          WSAStringToAddressW
          WSAUnadvertiseProvider
   110    WSAUnhookBlockingHook
          WSAWaitForMultipleEvents
          WSCDeinstallProvider
          WSCDeinstallProvider32
          WSCDeinstallProviderEx
          WSCEnableNSProvider
          WSCEnableNSProvider32
          WSCEnumNameSpaceProviders32
          WSCEnumNameSpaceProvidersEx32
          WSCEnumProtocols
          WSCEnumProtocols32
          WSCEnumProtocolsEx
          WSCGetApplicationCategory
          WSCGetApplicationCategoryEx
          WSCGetProviderInfo
          WSCGetProviderInfo32
          WSCGetProviderPath
          WSCGetProviderPath32
          WSCInstallNameSpace
          WSCInstallNameSpace32
          WSCInstallNameSpaceEx
          WSCInstallNameSpaceEx2
          WSCInstallNameSpaceEx32
          WSCInstallProvider
          WSCInstallProvider64_32
          WSCInstallProviderAndChains64_32
          WSCInstallProviderEx
          WSCSetApplicationCategory
          WSCSetApplicationCategoryEx
          WSCSetProviderInfo
          WSCSetProviderInfo32
          WSCUnInstallNameSpace
          WSCUnInstallNameSpace32
          WSCUnInstallNameSpaceEx2
          WSCUpdateProvider
          WSCUpdateProvider32
          WSCUpdateProviderEx
          WSCWriteNameSpaceOrder
          WSCWriteNameSpaceOrder32
          WSCWriteProviderOrder
          WSCWriteProviderOrder32
          WSCWriteProviderOrderEx
          WahCloseApcHelper
          WahCloseHandleHelper
          WahCloseNotificationHandleHelper
          WahCloseSocketHandle
          WahCloseThread
          WahCompleteRequest
          WahCreateHandleContextTable
          WahCreateNotificationHandle
          WahCreateSocketHandle
          WahDestroyHandleContextTable
          WahDisableNonIFSHandleSupport
          WahEnableNonIFSHandleSupport
          WahEnumerateHandleContexts
          WahInsertHandleContext
          WahNotifyAllProcesses
          WahOpenApcHelper
          WahOpenCurrentThread
          WahOpenHandleHelper
          WahOpenNotificationHandleHelper
          WahQueueUserApc
          WahReferenceContextByHandle
          WahRemoveHandleContext
          WahWaitForNotification
          WahWriteLSPEvent
   151    __WSAFDIsSet
     1    accept
     2    bind
     3    closesocket
     4    connect
          freeaddrinfo
          getaddrinfo
    51    gethostbyaddr
    52    gethostbyname
    57    gethostname
          getnameinfo
     5    getpeername
    53    getprotobyname
    54    getprotobynumber
    55    getservbyname
    56    getservbyport
     6    getsockname
     7    getsockopt
     8    htonl
     9    htons
    11    inet_addr
    12    inet_ntoa
          inet_ntop
          inet_pton
    10    ioctlsocket
    13    listen
    14    ntohl
    15    ntohs
    16    recv
    17    recvfrom
    18    select
    19    send
    20    sendto
    21    setsockopt
    22    shutdown
    23    socket
```

if we view ordinal not empty - API will be imported by ordinal (*if PE build by linking with this lib*) if empty - will be import by name. so say for example `WSAStartup` will be imported by ordinal 115 (0x73) when `WSASocketW` will be imported by name. if Microsoft library (`ws2_32.lib`) exported `WSAStartup` by ordinal 115 - this mean in ALL windows (x64) versions `WSAStartup` **must** be exported with same ordinal 115 - otherwise huge count of applications linked with this official lib - not started or crashed in runtime. so in future, some another version of `ws2_32.lib` **can** begin import `WSAStartup` by name, but all windows `ws2_32.dll` already must always export `WSAStartup` with 115 ordinal.

if you check `kernel32.lib` you can view that ordinals column all empty - so no any grantee about say `Sleep` ordinal - and it really very volatile.

so how need write code, for example detect `WSAStartup` import entry ?

```
#define WSAStartup_Ordinal 115

PVOID hmod;
PIMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR piid;
ULONG size/* size of IMPORT directory*/, d;
// assume hmod, piid, size already initialized

while ((INT)size >= sizeof(IMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR) && (d = piid->Name))
{
    PCSTR name = RtlOffsetToPointer(hmod, d);

    if (!_stricmp(name, "ws2_32.dll"))
    {
        if (d = piid->FirstThunk)
        {
            PIMAGE_THUNK_DATA FirstThunk = (PIMAGE_THUNK_DATA)RtlOffsetToPointer(hmod, d);

            if (d = piid->OriginalFirstThunk)
            {
                PIMAGE_THUNK_DATA OriginalFirstThunk = (PIMAGE_THUNK_DATA)RtlOffsetToPointer(hmod, d);

                while (ULONG_PTR Ordinal = OriginalFirstThunk->u1.Ordinal)
                {
                    ULONG_PTR Function = 0;

                    if (IMAGE_SNAP_BY_ORDINAL(Ordinal))
                    {
                        if (IMAGE_ORDINAL(Ordinal) == WSAStartup_Ordinal) // 115
                        {
                            Function = FirstThunk->u1.Function;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (!strcmp((PCSTR)((PIMAGE_IMPORT_BY_NAME)RtlOffsetToPointer(hmod, Ordinal))->Name, "WSAStartup"))
                        {
                            Function = FirstThunk->u1.Function;
                        }
                    }

                    if (Function)
                    {
                        __nop();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    size -= sizeof(IMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR), piid++;
}
```

Comment: Wow thank you for you answer :) Well you are right, actually the function I want to hook is ws2_32.sendto, but I cannot find it by name in the IAT, so I guessed it is imported by ordinal. I will continue to read your code till I understand it 100%, but thanks buddy :)

Comment: @User90234 - `sendto` have ordinal 20 - look in table which i paste

Comment: Just modified my function with your guide, works perfectly fine, thanks buddy :) May I ask you one more thing: What happens if two functions actually have the same ordinal? Like sendto has ordinal 20 and some other function of another dll has also ordinal 20? What would happen then?

Comment: in same dll can be only one function with this ordinal. are you check dll name ?

Comment: Oh, missed that part... seems logical, got it now :) Do you maybe know, pretty off-topic now though, why a game crashes if I overwrite a function of the IAT, but when I overwrite a IAT function of my test-application everything works? Are there some kind of protections possible I am not aware of? I am already altering the protection of the memory to READ_WRITE access. Sorry to bother you for so long

Comment: @User90234 - may be because you wrong implement your hook function. in all case you need debug code which crashed

Comment: well actually I did it the same way I did it in may own application...well I guess I need to look further, but thanks anyway buddy